# Ionic framework with Angular and Phonegap

Tags: cordova

How to start phone gap using iconic and angular framework.I have installed Phone gap don't know to use angular and iconic.

Comment: try asking more specific questions

Comment: Follow [these quick steps](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/). For a more indepth overview, watch the [Crash Course video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C-UwOWB9Io4&feature=youtu.be).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend to you this Course for Angular on codeschool [Shaping up with Angular.JS](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js).

It took me just 2-3 hours to understand the logic of Angular.js and really helped me out with this.

Inonic is just a UI framework to give your App a nice look&feel. They have quite a good documentation on their site.

To implement this stuff in a phonegap application just go ahead and take a look at the ionic Get Stated Guide to download the ressources and implement them in your www - folder of your phonegap dir.

But first of all, start with the course ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, install [NodeJs](http://nodejs.org/) on your system. Then follow the instructions given [here at Ionic website](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/). Make sure you have the Android/iOS SDK installed on your system.

I would highly recommend you to get started with the sample app here on [Christophe Coenraets's blog](http://coenraets.org/blog/2014/04/sociogram-angularjs-ionic-facebook/).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build your first ionic app, you can try this tool [Ionic builder](http://ionic-sarav.rhcloud.com/#/ionicbuilder/home)

This will help you to build a sample ionic project by just clicking a button and you can configure your pages as well. Once the project is generated, you can download the code and load it in "www" folder of phonegap app.